# Integrating LLVM-GCC with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, llvm, llvm-gcc

I'm currently doing some development on the llvm-gcc compiler, using llvm-gcc-4.2-2.0 front-end and the llvm-2.9 back-end. For about seven months I've been doing the development using text viewers, building the compiler using the terminal and debugging using print statements "you could probably imagine what kind of pain that is".

Here's what I need help with. **How do I integrate llvm and gcc into an Eclipse Juno IDE?**

I'm interested in building the compiler from eclipse, code completion and run-time debugging. I already tried integrating it but it didn't really work out, I keep getting errors in the source files, some header files can't be found and opened.

I would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks in advance.